# How to add Raster legends in QGIS map composer?

Tags: qgis, raster, printing

Is there a plugin or method to add legends for raster layers (with a custom colourmap) as an item in the print composer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous color band for a raster legend in QGIS composer legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91179/continuous-color-band-for-a-raster-legend-in-qgis-composer-legend)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Colour Scale Bar" is a plugin (QGIS contributed repository) which does this. It only works with discrete interpolation!

Once you have set up a raster layer in the way you like, you save the style (Layer|Properties... then click Save Style) and select the saved .qml file in the plugin dialogue.

The legend is saved as a PNG file, which you can then add as an image in the print composer.

[image: Elevation legend for E/C Africa map]]

Comment: No worries ... something I found confusing with the dialogue is that the 'box size' refers to the size of the colour patches in pixels, not the entire legend! Updated the graphic with a 20x30px patch size legend.

Answer (score 8):

You can use 1.8 version of QGIS or higher (QGIS master) to have raster legend in map composer available by default.

Comment: +1 - hadn't even noticed that option! That works with linear colormap, too, not just discrete.

Comment: ahhh, well, I'll have to wait for the release :)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this problem in this way: Once you have set up a raster layer in the way you like, press "Print Screen" while Colormap window it's open, then save it as image, and add it  in your map.