# Using continuous color band for raster legend in QGIS composer legend?

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, print-composer

I'm looking for a way to insert continuous colour legend for a raster layer. 
I managed to create discrete symbols with values along the bar, but I would like to have a continuous bar with some values on the bar, similar to the old plugin "One-Band Raster", that it doesn't work with the QGIS version higher than 1.7

I tried to set in properties->style, where I selected the  Render Type "Singleband pseudocolor" and see the "generate new color ramp" box.  I tried both "Continuous" or "Equal interval". However, in the Composer the legend always is displayed with discrete symbols.

Is there any way that can make QGIS Composer to display a nice continuous band for a raster layer?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible in QGIS for the legend item. The workaround is to create an image and insert it in composer. For continuous colors of the raster, select linear interpolation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A bit of a hack round to get composer to do this in QGIS 3

Add your legend, then adjust the symbol size in your legend to something small (example is 1.5mm). 
You'll still see white lines dividing the colour bands, these seem to relate to the font size for the legend text so set this to zero.

You can then add manual labels along the gradient and a rectangle to mask the legend text, or set that text to white.

This doesn't give a perfect gradient as some small white lines remain but for my purposes this was good enough.

Edit; This was tested on QGIS version 3.4.1-Madeira

As below;

[image]

Comment: I awarded a bounty to this answer because it was the only one that mentioned the version (albeit just the major release) number to which it applies.

Comment: You may also need to adjust the "Symbol space" under "Spacing" and uncheck the  box by "Draw stroke for raster symbols" under "Symbol"

Answer (score 73):

**Update:** QGIS 3.18 now has built in support for gradient color band legend items, so the previous workarounds are no longer necessary!

**For earlier versions:**

Another option is to add a rectangle shape to the composition, then style the rectangle using a gradient fill with the same color ramp as your raster. This can be done directly in QGIS, no image editing or html required.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't provide necessary measurements for the legend, though

Comment: Should provide QGIS version information.

Comment: how can I add text below this bar? I used "add label" but is there a less manual solution?

Comment: Here's a video tutorial on using the new functionality for QGIS 3.18+: https://youtu.be/cHhn1g5B6Do

Comment: You say that QGIS 3.18 has the option now but I can't seem to find it. I am on version 3.20.3-Odense. Can you explain more?
Just a quick clarification: I am dealing with a vector layer, not a raster.

Answer (score 15):

A workaround without pictures is to add the gradient using a HTML frame and some CSS magic:

```
<html> <head> <style type="text/css"> 
body { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,red,orange,yellow,green);  }
* { color: white;  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, sans; font-size: 24px;  }
</style></head>
<body> <div style="float:left">low value</div>
       <div style="float:right">high value</div>
</body> </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Note : this used to work with a regular text box by enabling html but now we have to use an html box. More details on this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469988/updating-pre-3-32-html-code

Answer (score 8):

An old question, but as I couldn't get the plugin mentioned above to work, here another work-around, tested on QGIS 3.12.3.

1. Add a legend with limited number of discrete classes (enough to
   capture the gradient).
2. In the composer, add the raster layer and legend.
3. Under symbol, reduce the height of the symbols (1), deselect the ‘draw stroke for raster symbol’ (2), and under spacing, increase the spacing between symbols (3).

[image]

4. Place a rectangle next to the legend, and select as style gradient fill.
5. Select the colour ramp, and then the option to edit it.
6. Now, add as many stops, minus two, as you have colours (1). Place the stops at the right relative distances (2) and use the sample colour function (3, 4) to define the colours.

[image]

7. Now you can move the rectangle on top of the legend symbols to complete it. Group the two together to make it easier to freely move the legend around. More details at [Ecodiv.earth](https://ecodiv.earth/post/legend-for-continuous-raster-in-qgis-composer/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This option is not included in QGIS but here is what I do:

First classify using desired color ramp.
Then go to Settings -> Style Manager -> Color Ramp (shows in figure below):
[image]

Now you can use 'Snipping Tool' to copy the ramp that you used. For example figure below shows the 'Blues' color ramp copied using snipping tool:

[image]

Now, in 'Composer Manager', use 'Add Label' and 'Add Image' to add continuous color ramp along with legend. To get the 'Max' and 'Min' value for continuous color ramp use, Layer Properties -> Style.

Answer (score 4):

There is a qgis plugin to do this in the main repository:  *Colour Scale Bar for One-Band Rasters* and works well for me
for QGIS 2.X
https://github.com/BC-Consulting/bccscbar
or QGIS 3.X
https://github.com/BC-Consulting/geoprocalgos

[image]

Comment: Could you please add install instructions?

Comment: At first I thought I had installed it wrong, but it seems this plug-in simply does not work. You might wish to revise or update your answer.

Comment: The plugin is working just fine and You will finde it in the main Plugin Repository look for Colour Scale Bar

Comment: This plugin is not for QGIS 3; developed for QGIS 2.x, and is backward compatible with .qml's generated with QGIS versions 1.x.

Comment: This plugin is not available anymore for even LST V2.18. The web link at the beginning of the answer is not valid anymore as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have changed the link to GitHub repo of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

yet another option, but limited to the cpt-city ramps.

This works

- if you have the Color Manager plugin installed and
- you've elected to install the cpt-city ramps

You can drop the svg ramp file onto the canvas as an image. On my ubuntu setup they appear under ~/.qgis2/cpt-city/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]In addition you might want to add a scale to your legend. You can do this by adding a scalebar. Play around with the units and segments to get the extent and segments you need.

1. Rotate the scale bar if need be to align it to your ramp.
2. Remove the units label or put an appropriate label.This will work for linear equally spaced units. 
   For non linear scales you can overlay multiple scale bars with different units and segments.

I am still figuring out how to rotate the text

Comment: This is the closest solution that I could consider, but it is still a hack. I wonder what was the reason to discontinue the One-Band Raster plugin?