# Continuous raster legend in QGIS map composer

Tags: qgis, raster, legend

Is it possible to make continuous raster legend in QGIS? Something like in ArcGIS???[image]

Comment: This would be a nice option to have in QGIS but at the moment, it's not available. This alternative might be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91179/continuous-color-band-for-a-raster-legend-in-qgis-composer-legend

Comment: Is this still not possible in QGIS?? Just can't believe it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112881)

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to produce it as a bitmap elsewhere.