# Creating a gradient-based legend

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer

I have a map with graduated symbology, with 328 unique values. I would like to add a legend to my map (as in the picture), illustrating that light blue indicates low values and dark blue high values.

I have done this in ArcGIS before. Is there a way to do this in QGIS as well?

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

Not sure there's a simple process to achieve this in QGIS, atleast not that I know of.

- To get a similar legend icon, you can follow this link: [Continuous color band for a raster legend in QGIS composer legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91179/continuous-color-band-for-a-raster-legend-in-qgis-composer-legend).
- To get the legend to say *High* or *Low*, you can achieve this by deleting everything inside the **Legend Format** textbox and then manually type "High" and "Low" in the symbol containing the maximum and minimum values respectively:

[image: Graduated Legend Format]

[image: Composer legend]

Answer (score 4):

***Update**: Since QGIS 3.18 gradient color band legend items are natively supported for **raster** layers. As of QGIS 3.28 constructing a gradient legend for **vector** layers still requires a workaround:*

Another workaround is to insert a 'Rectangle' shape with a Gradient Fill using the same color-ramp as your data. Overlay this rectangle over your legend.

Accuracy of this method may not be perfect, particularly if you use transform curves when assigning the color ramp to your data.

[image: Screencap of QGIS Print Composer showing a gradient-filled rectangle overlaid over legend]

Comment: I really can't see this option anywhere...and the image inserted in this answer is cropped; so I can't locate what dialog window is open. Can you clarify please?

Comment: The screenshot is showing a Print Layout window. In Print Layout you can insert shapes (Rectangle, in this case).
Note that this answer is outdated, as the functionality is now a core feature of QGIS since v3.18, so you no longer need to use this workaround.

Comment: I keep seeing comments mentioning that `QGIS has this feature now.` No, it doesn't. I am running `Vesion 3.30` and it doesn't have that feature for vector layers. It only has it for raster layers.

Comment: A very valid point, thanks for the correction. I'll update the note on this answer.
In this case we still need a workaround to show a gradient legend for vector layers. The new Raster Layer gradient legend item provides a new workaround option, so I will add another answer showing that option.

Answer (score 0):

Raster layers can be configured to display a gradient color-ramp legend. This functionality can be leveraged to create a faux legend to accompany a vector layer. This workaround is more convoluted than the other 'insert a rectangle' workaround, but it does result in a native legend item, which might be preferable in some situations.

For starters, here is my vector point layer styled using a color ramp. This screenshot shows a simple Print Layout consisting of a map and the default legend:
[image]

Now I add a random raster file to my project. I have added a small GeoTIFF of DEM data.
I then set its symbology to use the same color-ramp as the vector layer:
[image]

Next, in the Print Layout's legend's properties, I can configure the raster layer's legend item with values to make it **appear** to represent the vector layer:
[image]

Then I clean up the legend items, renaming the raster layer's entry in the legend, removing the *Band 1* sub-title, and removing the *My Vector Layer* legend item.
[image]

This results in a print layout like the following. Note that I have hidden the bogus raster layer from the map:

[image]

I can also use the *Orientation* parameter to make it a horizontal legend patch:
[image]