# QGIS Legend only with Raster Minimum and Maximum values

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, values

I want to have a mimim and maximum raster values in the legend but it appears to me a long list of all values how can I resume the legend minimum and maximum values:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Legend *Item Proprieties* tab deselect the *Auto Update* option, then select all the values that you want to remove and click on the red minus sign.

This will correct the Legend as you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked very well!!! and is good help however show a discrete max and min while in ArcGIS show automatically max and min and continuous color scale from max to min is this possible here as well?

Comment: It is not a default option yet, but there are some solution in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91179/using-continuous-color-band-for-raster-legend-in-qgis-composer-legend) post that can help you

Comment: thanks a lot regards