# QGIS 3.18 Override raster gradient legends

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer

In the new QGIS 3.18 (Zurich), raster color ramps automatically show up in the print layout as gradient legends! This is great, but I am trying to match some old maps to new maps for a publication and would prefer the old categorical legend type.

The change log mentions there is a way to override this behavior, however I have not been able to find it.
(https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#id32)

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388154/how-to-get-back-discrete-raster-legend-symbols-in-qgis-3-16 Add a discussion on Twitter thread about it at https://twitter.com/ThomasG77/status/1365255399927140355 Maybe something useful (or not)

Comment: Try the solution posted on the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this functionality should be back in QGIS 3.18.1 next week.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/42193