# Adding more values to legend on print composer tool of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, bathymetry

I am creating a map with a bathymetry layer (raster) on the print composer tool of QGIS. On the legend it only appears the minimum depth and the maximum depth.

Is there a way on QGIS to show more values between the min and the max on the legend?

[image]

Comment: Please check this answer if it helps you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388867/63384

Answer (score 5):

In the Layer Styling panel of the raster, click `Legend Settings` and uncheck the box next to `Use continuous legend`:

[image]