# QGIS graduated symbology legend with color ramp instead of classes

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer and I defined the symbology using graduated. I specify the color ramp and the number of classes. QGIS create the legend symbology where it defines "classes" of color where each feature falls in (see image).

[image]

I would like to know if it possible to have a continous color ramp: if I look at the tree or at a legend in a layout I only see the classes, while I would like to see the usual color ramp with the ticks and values. As an example I show the bar plotted by ArcGIS. It is not "continous" because it has too few classes, bat it is a single bar, not this set of rows like in qgis.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of "the usual color ramp with the ticks and values"?

Comment: I think you need to apply the solution suggested in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91179/using-continuous-color-band-for-raster-legend-in-qgis-composer-legend/287399#287399)

Comment: I edited the question to add an example

Comment: Thanks Kasper for your suggestion. I am also afraid this is the only solution. It is strange thought that qgis has to "class" features attributes and not compute on the fly the color based on the simple linear mapping given by the chosen ramp...