# Updating pre-3.32 HTML code in label boxes

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, html

Since QGIS 3.32, HTML formatting in composer text boxes works differently and code snippets like this example that used to display a linear gradient no longer work :

```html
<html> <head> <style type="text/css">
body { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,#ffffff,#3ad3fd,#8ecd10,#ffea01,#fe003b,#8901ff);  }
* { color: white}
</style></head>
<body>
This is an HTML gradient!
</body> </html>
```

I'm told from [this issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53919#issuecomment-1780723518) that:

> since 3.32, users have to rely on HTML item (instead of an HTML-enabled label item) when wanting to rely on `<style>` tags

... which seems to refer to [this change](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog332/index.html#feature-hyperlink-support-for-html-enabled-label-exports) but the changelog doesn't point to any github commit and not being an html guru, I couldn't find the difference between an "HTML item" and an "HTML-enabled label item". Googling it seemingly yields no related result so I'm stuck in my research.

Is there a way to fix this HTML snippet to make it work in QGIS 3.32?

Comment: here is the code [commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/26406fe98d1b27cafb5b6d9de9afbdf5fdeaadc8), including the test project/data

Comment: Thank you! The test file helped a lot. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the composer, we now have to use the html box tool instead of the regular label box:

[image]

With this type of box the code works:

[image]

Thanks to @JGH for helping me unlock this mystery.